how do i extract the x and y coordinates of the bounding boxes
my code defines a ROS node for object detection in images using the YOLO algorithm, specifically with a YOLO model loaded from a specified file path. The node subscribes to a ROS topic (/camera/color/image_raw) that broadcasts images. Upon receiving an image, the callback function is triggered, converting the ROS image message to an OpenCV image format using CvBridge. This image is then processed by the YOLO model to detect objects. The results, including detected object boxes, are printed to the console. To prevent continuous processing and reprocessing of images, a flag (image_processed) is set after the first image is processed. Additionally, the processed image is saved to a specified folder (temporary). The node remains active, listening for new images, until it is manually shut down.
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import os
from ultralytics import YOLO

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.yolo_model = YOLO('/home/user/catkin_ws/src/run_folder/content/runs/obb/train/weights/best.pt')
        self.br = CvBridge()
        self.image_processed = False  # Flag to indicate if the image has been processed

        # Subscribe to the ROS topic that publishes images
        rospy.Subscriber("/camera/color/image_raw", Image, self.callback)

    def callback(self, msg):
        if not self.image_processed:  # Process only if no image has been processed yet
            image = self.br.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg)  # Convert ROS Image message to OpenCV image

            # Perform object detection with YOLO
            results = self.yolo_model.predict(image, show=True)
            for r in results[0]:
                print("---------------------------")
                print(r.boxes)

            # Save the image after processing it for the first time
            self.save_image(image, 'temporary')
            self.image_processed = True  # Set the flag to True to avoid re-processing

    def save_image(self, image, folder_name):
        if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
            os.makedirs(folder_name)
        
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, 'image.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(file_path, image)
        print(f"Image saved at {file_path}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("image_processor_with_yolo", anonymous=True)
    node = Node()
    rospy.spin()  # Keep the node running until shutdown


when i try to extract the boundary boxes i get "none" in the output.

With Yolo8:
For the box in format xyxy
from ultralytics import YOLO


model =YOLO('best.pt')

results = model(image, show=True)

result = results[0]
res = result.boxes[0] 
cords = res.xyxy[0].tolist()
cords = [round(x) for x in cords]
class_id = result.names[res.cls[0].item()]
conf = round(res.conf[0].item(), 2)

print("Coordinates:", cords)
print("Probability:", conf)
print("Object type:", class_name)

I added the confidence and the class!
If you want to crop and resize the bounding box image :
import cv2
import numpy as np

size=128

img_cropped = cv2.resize(np.array(result.orig_img[cords[1]:cords[3],cords[0]:cords[2]]), (128, 128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

